# Configure cannot find intltool installed in custom path

Tags: linux, compiling, transmission, autotools

I'm trying to build [transmission-2.94](https://github.com/transmission/transmission-releases/raw/master/transmission-2.94.tar.xz) on a remote server where I have no privileged access. I, therefore, wanna install all custom software under `~/.local`.
I have successfully installed `gettext` and `intltool` with `PATH` and `PKG_CONFIG_PATH` set-up.

```
[user@remote transmission-2.94]$ intltool-update --version
intltool-update (intltool) 0.50.2
Written by Kenneth Christiansen, Maciej Stachowiak, and Darin Adler.

Copyright (C) 2000-2003 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.
[user@remote transmission-2.94]$ gettext --version
gettext (GNU gettext-runtime) 0.19
Copyright (C) 1995-1997, 2000-2007 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later <http://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>
This is free software: you are free to change and redistribute it.
There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.
Written by Ulrich Drepper.
[user@remote transmission-2.94]$
```

However, when I run `./configure --prefix=${HOME}/.local --enable-utp --enable-cli --enable-daemon --disable-gtk`, I still get the following error:

```
checking system miniupnpc library... none
configure: error: "--enable-nls requires intltool to be installed."
```

I'm pretty sure my current bash can find `intltool` and `gettext` currectly.

```
[user@remote transmission-2.94]$ which intltool-extract
~/.local/bin/intltool-extract
[user@remote transmission-2.94]$ which intltool-merge  
~/.local/bin/intltool-merge
[user@remote transmission-2.94]$ which intltool-prepare
~/.local/bin/intltool-prepare
[user@remote transmission-2.94]$ which intltool-update 
~/.local/bin/intltool-update
[user@remote transmission-2.94]$ which intltoolize    
~/.local/bin/intltoolize
[user@remote transmission-2.94]$ which gettext
~/.local/bin/gettext
[user@remote transmission-2.94]$ which gettextize
~/.local/bin/gettextize
[user@remote transmission-2.94]$
```

Any ideas?